# DDNS + DHCPD : Once lease runs out, does DNS entry get removed?

Tags: dhcp, ttl, ddns

Once there are several hundred adhoc machines being brought up, each with a unique name. Their hostname gets added to the DNS.

Then upon TTL expiring, will the DNS entry still be reachable, or if the host has been down for some-time, it [dns-entry] will be cleared?

What's the best way to manipulate these timeouts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for saying what you run.  That helps a lot :)

ISC DHCP and BIND are sort of hands-off with each other.  DHCP will maintain the DNS records, but BIND will not automatically expire them.  However, DHCP should.

Comment: My apologies. You are correct.

Am using bind 9.5.2 and dhcpd 4.0.0

Answer (score -1):

DNS will tomb stone the record and they will then be removed from DNS.